# Can transverse waves be both mechanical and non-mechanical?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, aether

Transverse waves need a medium for particles to propagate perpendicular to the wave right? Then how can transverse waves be non mechanical which do not require any medium?

Comment: It is the story of the aether, EM field is non material it is a property of space. In the contrary if a string made of matter is considered, or waves of coordinates, then transverse waves correspond to movement of space and cannot go faster than c.

Comment: I've just spotted that [Why electromagnetic waves are considered to be transverse?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/750387/why-electromagnetic-waves-are-considered-to-be-transverse) is probably a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 4):

The meanings of *transverse* and *longitudinal* are subtly different for a non-mechanical wave.

Suppose we consider an electromagnetic wave. With an EM wave it is the strength of the electric and magnetic fields that oscillates in time. For example if we take a point in space and measure how the electric field changes in time then we find it oscillates between some values $+E_0$ and $-E_0$ according to:

$$ E = E_0 \sin(\omega t) $$

So nothing is moving. All that happens is the strength of a field is changing. However an electric field has a direction, and in particular the direction of the field can be perpendicular or parallel to the direction of motion of the wave. If the electric and magnetic fields are perpendicular to the direction of motion of the wave we call the wave *transverse* and if the direction of the field is parallel to the direction of motion we call it *longitudinal*.

EM waves are usually transverse though there are special circumstances, for example in waveguides, where the wave can have a longitudinal component.

Answer (score 0):

Transverse waves are waves that propagate in the direction perpendicular to the motion of the wave. Longitudinal waves are waves that propagate in the direction of the motion of the wave. Mechanical waves are waves that require a medium to propagate while non mechanical waves are waves that do not require a medium to propagate.

Mechanical waves can either be transverse or longitudinal, same case is with non mechanical waves.

Comment: Normally the direction of propagation of a wave is defined to be the direction it is moving.  Saying that a wave "propagates in the direction perpendicular to the motion of the wave" is confusing at best.